# Windows 2003 DNS updates from ISC DHCP server

Tags: domain-name-system, dhcp, isc-dhcp

We have a very mixed network, with most clients being Debian Lenny, the rest Windows XP/Vista/7. The network itself is split into two segments (for technical reasons) called "corporate" and "engineering". On the "corporate" side all clients get their IP addresses from a Windows DHCP server and the dynamic updates into the Windows DNS work just fine.
On the "engineering" side, clients get their IP addresses from a linux machine running the standard ISC DHCP server. Although this server is configured to do dynamic DNS updates, they actually don't work. Anybody got any advice on how to fix this?

Please note: dynamic updates from the clients directly into the DNS would work, but are not an option for us. So this is strictly on how make this work from an ISC DHCP server to a Windows DNS server.

Comment: Have you looked at the DNS server logs for information?

Comment: Yes, and there is absolutely nothing in it. No warnings, no errors, nothing at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would try running Wireshark to capture the traffic between the ISC DHPC server and your Windows DNS servers.  The logging for Microsoft DNS is certainly not perfect, so this would be helpful.

That being said, are you restrict updates in DNS to "secure" updates (meaning authenticated connections only)?  If so, my guess is that the ISC server cannot authenticate against the Windows DNS infrastructure and the updates are failing.  I would try turning unsecured updates in that case assuming this is a private/trusted network.

Comment: Yes, this is a private network. I haven't checked yet, but I believe the default is for all domains in Windows DNS to only allow secure updates, so I would suspect that this is the case here (this was all set up yonks ago before my time and without any documentation)